# What's the Probability Of Non-Defective Mobiles?

Tags: probability

In a shipment of 100 mobiles,6 are found defective.If Arpit buys two mobile from that shipment,what is probability of both-being non-defective ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please provide details about what you have tried so far, or where you are stuck.

Comment: $\frac{94\cdot93}{100\cdot99}$

Answer (score 0):

The sample space would be selecting any $2$ mobiles from the $100$. So, sample space is $^{100}C_2$.

Arpit wants both the mobiles to be non-defective. So, he must select $2$ mobiles from the $94$ non-defective ones. So, the number of possible ways of doing that is $^{94}C_2$

Hence, you have the probability $$P=\frac{^{94}C_2}{^{100}C_2}=\frac{(94)(93)}{(100)(99)}$$